# Creating many different folders at once

Tags: r

I'm glad to find this website. 
I want to know how create many folders at once in R. 
I know "dir.create" function, but I can't.

This is what I tried.

```
for (i in 1 : length(names)) {
  name = names[i,1]
  ifelse(dir.exists('users/',name), False, dir.create('users/',name))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dir_names <- c('a','b','c')

for (dir in dir_names){
  if (!dir.exists(file.path('users',dir))) dir.create(file.path('users',dir))
}
```